# Excel VBA Copy Macro Code into Excel Tab

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know how to copy the contents of multiple modules into a worksheet code? this can all be in the same workbook. Because if I dump all my module code into a single sheet and MOVE that sheet, the code moves with it.

Diagram of workflow:

https://snag.gy/9NDVZI.jpg

1. Starting with the Core XLS WORKBOOK .
2. Engineer executes the compile script on the Core WORKBOOK .
3. All code modules combine together .
4. The code that was combined is copied to the
   code of the Compile WORKSHEET .
5. Compile WORKSHEET has the code .
6. Compile WORKSHEET is moved to a new WORKBOOK (Book1)

I technically don't need to make a new module with the combined code, I am just trying to get all the code from the other modules dumped into the 'Compile' tab before I move it.

Update: I am just trying to get my code into a new worksheet using VBA script. THE KEY SOLUTION needs to work on both MAC and PC. This would also work if I could find the code to make it happen https://snag.gy/82tHSZ.jpg .

Comment: I don't really understand your question, but code stored 'behind' a sheet is a special version of a Class module and is different from a normal module. Subs become methods of the sheet, functions become Properties and so on. SO I would never put code there without special reason.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I need to move multiple modules into a new worksheet via VBA, I've been searching for two days now and haven't found a way to do this. However, I manually copied all my code to the 'compile' sheet and ran the compile process and all my buttons in the new worksheet, worked fine. Which is what my goal is. I don't want to copy my modules, manually, everytime I compile. When I right-cick on Compile > View Code, and dump all the code from my modules into it (the functions and subs) everything works. Also, this needs to work on Mac and PC (Office 365). Check the diagram flow.

Comment: Insert your explanation into your question @JeremyWheeler

Comment: Don't you mix the terms `worksheet` and `workbook` ?

Comment: https://translate.google.lu/#fr/en/Pourquoi%20faire%20simple%20quand%20on%20peut%20faire%20compliqu%C3%A9%20%3F  :-)

Comment: I am trying to accomplish one of these options: 

https://snag.gy/kg4wc7.jpg

or

https://snag.gy/9NDVZI.jpg

and whatever solution it is, it needs to work on a Mac and PC. Thanks!

Comment: I thought my explanation with diagrams pretty-much spelled out exactly what I am trying to do here. The key is the solution needs to work on a Mac also. With a lot of googling and testing, copying the code to a worksheet and moving the worksheet is the only solution i found that worked so far. I would prefer something easier, but have yet to find it.

Answer (score 0):

The functionality that you are looking for is in the reference

```
Microsoft Visual Basic for Applications Extensibility
```

using the namespace `VBIDE`.

This having been said, you should probably reconsider your approach. It is generally considered a bad idea to use this functionality and many antivirus programs will consider any workbook using this a virus.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am open to any approach, I just need to move the module code to the new worksheet somehow. Also, I need this to work on a Mac also. The solution you provided with 'Vbe6ext.olb' doesn't work on a Mac.

Comment: I would suggest saving a copy of the entire workbook so that the original modules are still accesible.

Comment: After i click compile, it creates a new workbook and moves tabs over from the source workbook. I close the source workbook (and dont save it) and with the new Book1 Workbook, I save it and currently, manually add the modules to it.